# meta_value_num not ordering all items

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, meta-query, order

I am using meta_value_num to output a list of items in order by a custom field. The custom field value that is being passed is 1, 2 ,3 or 4. The order works for the first 7 items but after that they are no longer outputted in order but are random.

**HTML/PHP:**

```
<div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
    <?php
      $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'       => 'work',
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'meta_key'        => 'work_category',
        'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'           => 'ASC'
      ));
      $i=0;
    ?>
    <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul class="swiper-wrapper">
      <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
      <li 
        id="<?php echo $i; ?>" 
        class="swiper-slide gallery-image <?php echo ($i==0)?'is-active':''; ?>"
        data-cat="<?php echo get_field('work_category') ?>"
        style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_field('image'); ?>');">
      </li>
      <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
</div>
```

**Here is a screenshot of the outputted order:**
[image]

**Here is a screenshot of the custom field in the functions.php:**
[image]

**Here is a screenshot of the database:**
[image]

Comment: have you checked the value of the field in the database? It's possible that the field is serialized, and so meta_value_num would not work.

Comment: @gdaniel I searched through the database and some of the items have no values or I cannot find where the relational data is stored. Im not sure what you mean by serialized (database add default id?).

Comment: all custom fields are stored in wp_postmeta table. Go there and search where meta_key = work_category and you should find your fields. Some custom field plugins serialize the data using the php function serialize(). That's used when a fields has multiple/combination of values such as an array. I am not saying that's the case for your site, but it's possible. I had this issue using Advanced Custom Fields (plugin) relationship field.

Comment: it looks like they're all just ordered by post ID. `var_dump` the contents of `$the_query` after you run it and look at the actual SQL getting sent to the database to make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: @gdaniel I added a picture of my database above showing the values that are being stored.

Comment: No issues there. Try Milo's suggestion.

Comment: While I prefer a proper meta query, that looks right if your data is stored as single values in the database. Post the output of `var_dump($the_query->request)` please.